# $\frac{3}{2}\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-\cos4x}}dx>\cot2a \, +\, \cot2b$

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math

Prove that if $0<a<b<\frac{\pi}{2}$ then;
$$\frac{3}{2}\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-\cos4x}}dx>\cot2a \, +\, \cot2b$$

---

This is pretty much all I could do on this integral;

$$I=\frac{3}{2}\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-\cos4x}}dx$$

$$I=\frac{3}{2^{\frac{7}{3}}}\int_{2a}^{2b} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\sin^2(x)}}dx$$

This integral clearly involved something beyond what I've learnt so far as none of my elementary substitutions simplified, so here's the [closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2CCbrt%5B1-cos4x%5D%5D%2Cx%5D), but on some exploration, I managed to find [Handbook of Elliptical Integrals](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjBmI7fp5GEAxWyUGwGHcYqDOsQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FToshio_Fukushima%2Fpublication%2F320194984_Byrd_and_Friedman%2527s_Handbook_of_Elliptic_Integrals_for_Engineers_and_Scientists_2nd_edn_Byrd_and_Friedman_1971%2Fdata%2F59d44ed8a6fdcc181ad95565%2FHandbookEllipticIntegrals.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1Yt0CRAUsYhy7a-b6-M6Qy&opi=89978449) on page $243$, section $521.03$, a similar integral. However, it was not making sense on how to interlink those two. I am interested in hints/explanation on how to proceed further.

EDIT(1):

As visible in the comments, the inequality is incorrect and the suggested inequality to prove is;

$$\frac{3}{2}\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-\cos4x}}dx<\cot2a \, -\, \cot2b$$

Comment: Is that the correct formula? For $a$ close to $b$ the integral on the left is arbitrarily small, and the right-hand side is not.

Comment: @MartinR, that formula is correct, i did check the source again, however youre also right, see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=cot%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bpi%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2Bcot%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bpi%2C3%5D%5C%2841%29) and [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2CCbrt%5B1-cos4x%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2CDivide%5Bpi%2C6%5D%2CDivide%5Bpi%2C4%5D%7D%5D), here's the source on W21 https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~perfetti/lavori/Wildt-2017.pdf

Comment: My guess is that the right-hand side should be $\cot (2a) - \cot(2b)$.

Comment: Actually one can show that $\frac{3}{2}\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-\cos4x}}dx <\cot2a - \cot2b$.

Comment: It is good that you added a reference, but the inequality is definitely wrong. With $a = \pi/8 - \epsilon$, $b = \pi/8+\epsilon$ and $\epsilon \to 0$ the LHS converges to zero and the RHS converges to $2$.

Comment: Are you interested in a proof of the revised inequality?

Answer (score 0):

$$
I = \frac{3}{2}\int_a^b \frac{dx}{({1-\cos(4x))}^\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{3}{2^{\frac{7}{3}}}\int_{2a}^{2b} \frac{dx}{(\sin^2 x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}
$$
$$
\cot (2a)-\cot(2b) = \int_{2a}^{2b}\frac{dx}{\sin^2x}
$$
$$
\forall x\in D, \frac{1}{\sin^2x} > \frac{1}{(\sin^2 x)^{\frac{1}{3}}} \Rightarrow \forall x\in D, \frac{1}{\sin^2x} >\frac{1}{(\sin^2 x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}>\frac{3}{2^{\frac{7}{3}}} \frac{1}{(\sin^2 x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \int_{2a}^{2b}\frac{dx}{\sin^2x} >  \frac{3}{2^{\frac{7}{3}}}\int_{2a}^{2b} \frac{dx}{(\sin^2 x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \cot (2a)-\cot(2b) > \frac{3}{2}\int_a^b \frac{dx}{({1-\cos(4x))}^\frac{1}{3}}
$$
with $2a, 2b \in D$ where $D$ is an interval in which both functions are continuous and defined.